# Hibernate Many to Many Relations Set Or List?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, list, set

I have a many to many relationship at my Java beans. When I use `List` to define my variables as like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ScD")
public class Group extends Nameable {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="b_fk")
    private List<R> r;
    //or
    private Set<R> r;
```

I get that error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'
...
```

When I use `Set` everything seem to work well.

I want to ask that when using many to many relationships which one to use for logical consept `List` or `Set` (because of list may have duplicates and set but what about performance and other issues)?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From relational databases perspective this is a set. Databases do not preserve order and using a `List` is meaningless, the order in them is unspecified (unless using so called *indexed collections*).

Using a `Set` also has great performance implications. When `List` is used, Hibernate uses `PersistentBag` collection underneath which has some terrible characteristics. I.e.: if you add a new relationship it will first delete all existing ones and then insert them back + your new one. With `Set` it just inserts the new record.

Third thing - you cannot have multiple `List`s in one entity as you will get infamous *cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags* exception.

See also:

- [19.5. Understanding Collection performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-collections)
- [Why Hibernate does "delete all then re-insert" - its not so strange](http://assarconsulting.blogspot.com/2009/08/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-then-re.html)

Comment: Beside many to many relationship(one-one, many-one, one-many) should I use `Set` instead of `List` too for a good design pattern?

Comment: Yes, because `List` suggests that items are ordered which is not true. I know, I know it has slightly easier API.

Comment: both voting up accepting as answer for detailed information and good links.

Comment: I want to ask just to make it more clear. When I remove just one element at using List with indexed columns does remove just one (as like Set) or removes all and insert all except that removed element?

Comment: If you are using **indexed** collection (index column), only single DELETE will occur. I think the second link has pretty good explanation of that.

Comment: Last question to understand whole things. What is the difference between using Set and Indexed List for both database and Java side performance and etc. Same or not?

Comment: They are different from a database perspective. `Set` maps directly to relational databases' many-to-many relationship. Indexed `List` on the other hand requires an extra column in join table but allows you to preserve order within the relationship. Often useful.

Answer (score 3):

How about the uniqueness requirement from Set? Doesn't this force Hibernate to retrieve all objects each time one is added to the collection to make sure a newly added one is unique? A List wouldn't have this limitation.

Comment: List has also this limitation, because hibernate needs to preserver order in Lists, so it also has to retrieve all items

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was made years ago but I wanted to comment on this topic, just in case someone is doubtful about the set vs list issue.

Regarding *lazy fetching*, I think a **bag** (list without index) would be a better option due to the fact that you avoid retrieving all objects each time one is added to the collection to:

- make sure a newly added one is unique, in case you are using a **set**
- preserve order, in case you are using a **list** (with index)

Please correct me if I'm mistaken.