# Parent has List of child. Single record of child in database. But on debug it shows 2 records with same id

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a parent entity ParentClass. In this parent Entity I have a list of child classes as shown below:-

```
public class BaseClass{
   @Id
   private Long  id;
}

@Entity
public class ParentClass extends BaseClass{

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<ChildClassA> childClassAList;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<ChildClassB> childClassBList;

}
```

In my database I only have one record for ChildClassA mapped to ParentClass(say my parent_class record has id 25001 and their is only one child mapped to this parent[from ChildClassA entity] say 45001) in my third table. But still when I am debugging parentClass.getchildClassAList(), It shows me 2 items in this list(and that too both with same ID) instead of one single record as shown below:-

```
ParentClass parentRecord = myDao.find(ParentClass.class,25001L); //shows only one record which is expected.

List<ChildClassA> allChildsOfParent = parentRecord.getchildClassAList();  //shows 2 items in list,each with same id 45001 even though the third table in db carries one single record corresponding to this parent with id 25001.
```

What could be the possible reason for this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Set instead of List for your `@OneToMany` relationship container

Comment: Yes i can do that but what could be the possible fix with using list only. I don't want to use set as my entity structure is quite complicated and I don't want to change it to list.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174667/hibernate-many-to-many-relations-set-or-list, there's some discussion about using List vs Set which might help